# Excel advanced vlookups for a schedule comparison

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup

I wondering if anyone will be able to help me sort the formula below out:

```
=IFERROR((VLOOKUP($D96,August!$C:$P,F$78,FALSE))-(VLOOKUP($D96,July!$C:$O,(F$78+1),FALSE)),IF(U96="NEW PART",(VLOOKUP($D96,July!$C:$O,(F$78+1),FALSE)),IF(V96="NEW PART",(VLOOKUP($D96,August!$C:$O,(F$78),FALSE)),"")))
```

Originally the formula was

```
=IFERROR((VLOOKUP($D95,August!$C:$P,F$78,FALSE))-(VLOOKUP($D95,July!$C:$O,(F$78+1),FALSE)),"BLANK")
```

However rather than returning "BLANK" if either sheet does not include that part number I would like the formula to return the figure on the one sheet they appear on. Columns U and V highlight weather the product number is on each sheet. These figures would be + figures if they appear in august and minus figures if they appear in July.

[image: Image of sheet where i want the formula working]

Comment: This wouldn't return BLANK if either sheet has BLANK - it would return FALSE - right?

Comment: @JCounter - not sure if you saw the updated solution below - if no response/feedback shall assume this solution not what you're looking for and remove accordingly.  Kindly advise, ta

Answer (score 0):

[Link](https://1drv.ms/x/s!AsxYl9DXJ0j98hB79sEOY33vAcyS?e=4cAZGV)/screenshot refer:

*In short - replace final 'FALSE' with an additional iferror(Aug,-July)*

*(see revision at end, following comments / feedback re sound applications/customizing soln as required)..*

**Formula - per OP request**

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(H4,B4:C14,2,FALSE)-VLOOKUP(H4,E4:F14,2,FALSE),IFERROR(VLOOKUP(H4,B4:C14,2,FALSE),-VLOOKUP(H4,E4:F14,2,FALSE)))
```

[image: OP version - modified as req.]

**Improvised version**

*(pre-requisite: Office 365 compatible version of Excel)*

```
=LET(A,INDEX(C4:C14,MATCH(H4#,B4:B14,0)),B,INDEX(F4:F14,MATCH(H4#,E4:E14,0)),IFERROR(A-B,IFERROR(A,-B)))
```

[image: Improvised | Preferred - s.t. pre-req.]

*Motive*

Arguments in favour of this version include:

1. OP version: 127 chars (vs 104) i.e. ~20-25% length reduction on this basis
2. Audit/review - arguably easier given let function
3. Flexibility: unless you plan to take advantage of vlookup 'approximate matching' (using True flag instead of False), Index more robust in that it can handle forward and backward references in relation to the indexed column (i.e. with vlookup, index has to lie to left of the column comprising the cell to be returned)

The usual benefits assoc. with 'spill' ranges (i.e. potential for 'dynamic' range feature and automatic calc. from single cell entry)

---

REVISION:

The following screenshot should shed some light on references/ranges you may wish to alter for 1st formula in present response to operate as you intend within your workbook (corresponding ranges are colour-coded with clear visual link between each)...

[image: Ranges requiring potential updates]

So to apply in your case, you'd need to replace shaded/boxed ranges/references in my proposal with those you're using (as indicated - i.e. replace by H4 with your $D95 etc,..."

> JB: *replace final 'FALSE' with an additional iferror(Aug,-July)*

This concept is clearly delineated within screenshot above.

> OP: *"I tried and just got N/A"*

*As link in opening line provides evidence of two alternative solns. working error-free, presume 'n/a' result of incorrect application...*

Comment: You answer just confuses me unfortunately. 
If your statement "In short - replace final 'FALSE' with an additional iferror(Aug,-July)" is the case then would you mind rewriting the first formula I placed in the question with it? I tried and just got N/A.
I also tried your first code but that just highlights an error in the formula.

Comment: Advice would be to customize my soln to suit your specific needs/set up re ranges, sheet names etc.  You can see my formula works just fine from the screenshots - if still in doubt then follow the link to the OneDrive excel sheet that demonstrates error-free (unless there is something you know that I do not).  To apply this formula correctly in first instance, replicate my set up / column ranges using formula in cell K3 (link per screenshots).  See my update that should get you started re application/customization (best way to learn!) unless I'm missing something - kindly enlighten me if so...

Comment: (if you give what I propose a go, and you're still not coming right, I'll attempt another way to assist - if that fails, I'll retract proposed answer in anticipation of this encouraging someone else to put forward '1st working soln' in absence of any other... trust in order)